# how do i fix Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Tags: swift, swiftui, macos-catalina

hi i'm making a game but i can't get an if state to work

now i added the full code of the program (contentView.swift)

hope its more useful to help me

the code is made in xcode and the program is for macos

coded in xcode whit swiftui

plz do not use this code its copyrighted by me

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var sp = false
    @State private var loaded = false
    @State private var uname = ""
    @State private var text = "input a number"
    @State private var etext = ""
    @State private var sats = ""
    @State private var mbt = "select collor"
    @State private var gameState = 0
    @State private var data = 0
    @State private var temp = 0
    @State private var type = 0
    @State private var collor = 0
    @State private var intsats = 0
    //@State private var password = ""
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if sp == false {
                Text("Alien entertaiment presentate\n\n")
                Text("casino\n\n")
                Button(action: {
                    self.sp = true
                    //self.loadEndings()
                    //self.load()
                }) {
                    Text("Start")
                }
                Text("\n\n")
            }else if sp == true && loaded == false {
                TextField("user name", text: $uname)
                //SecureField("pasword", text: $password)
                Text(uname)
                //Text(password)
                Button(action: {
                    self.loaded = true
                    self.load()
                }) {
                    Text("sign in")
                }
                
            }else if sp == true && loaded == true {
                Text("\(data)")
                Text("\n")
                Text(etext)
                if etext != "" {Text("\n")}
                Text("\n")
                //Text(text)
                Text("\n")
                if gameState == 0 {
                    MenuButton(mbt) {
                        Button("red", action: {self.mbt = "red"; self.collor = 1})
                        Button("black", action: {self.mbt = "red"; self.collor = 2})
                    }
                    TextField("a number", text: $sats)
                    Button(action: {
                        self.intsats = Int(self.sats) ?? 0
                        if self.intsats == 0 || self.intsats > self.data {
                            self.etext = "not valid number or you do not have enuf mony"
                        }else{
                            self.gameState = 1
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("bet")
                    }
                }else if gameState == 1
                {
                    if self.rand() == self.collor
                    { //Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
                        self.text = "you won"
                        self.data = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    func save()
    {
        defaults.set(self.data, forKey: uname)
    }
    func load()
    {
        self.data = defaults.integer(forKey: uname)
        self.temp = data
        if temp == 0 {
            self.data = 86
        }
    }
    func rand() -> Int
    {
        var type = 0
        type = Int.random(in: 1..<3)
        return type
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

ops just filing

the game is for mac os catalina and can be use for probobly all appels stuff that can have apps on it

Comment: try to change the name of the type to viewType and then check ...

Comment: where is code? I think you made your example too minimalistic to understand what's going on

Comment: jawadAli i tested it and it did not work and New Dev now you have the full code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in the `body` of the View you need to return a view. You can't just perform calculations etc. like in a *normal* function.

You can remove this code (which doesn't return a View and thus the compilation is failing):

```
else if gameState == 1 {
    if self.rand() == self.collor {
        self.text = "you won"
        self.data = 1
    }
}
```

and place it in you button's action:

```
if gameState == 0 {
    ...
    TextField("a number", text: $sats)
    Button(action: {
        self.intsats = Int(self.sats) ?? 0
        if self.intsats == 0 || self.intsats > self.data {
            self.etext = "not valid number or you do not have enuf mony"
        } else {
            self.gameState = 1
            if self.rand() == self.collor { // <- move it here
                self.text = "you won"
                self.data = 1
            }
        }
    }) {
        Text("bet")
    }
}
```